# Any DM not working on fedora

Tags: fedora, rhel, tigervnc

I was just trying to use vncserver and unfortunately I cluttered every thing, what should I do now to start GDM again. whenever I reboot I see a black screen, I searched a lot but there's not a single thing to repair this. And I also got failed to start vncserver.service on start.

I tried running `# systemctl restart gdm.service` , `# systemctl restart lightdm.service` and I had disabled wayland. Nothing Happened.

Comment: Does this work?  As root: `systemctl isolate graphical.target`

Comment: I am having problem in xorg itself, it is saying that xauth file /home/root/.Xauthority file not exists

Comment: Root’s homedir normally isn’t /home/root on Fedora or RHEL, and you shouldn’t be logging into X as root anyway.

Comment: Oops it /root sorry, so what should i do